# Formatting paragraph using jodatime

Tags: java, jodatime

I am trying to convert datetime object to String base on user defined pattern.

For example if a user pass in a string **"Good morning, today is E MM/dd/yyyy."**, I will replace the date format to the current time.

**"Good morning, today is Fri 11/15/2013."**

It is possible to handle by `joda time library`? or do I have to search for each possible pattern and do a string replace manually?

Comment: You should be able to mark the text as a literal, take a look at [formatting](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/key_format.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic when it comes to detecting and parsing date strings.

How will you know which parts are static text and which parts are formatting characters? Can you rely on users to know and type a format string? Most users I know have a difficult time just typing in a valid *date*.

If there were some rule such as "the word *is* will always be a delimiter between text and formatting", then Yes you could either [a] create a formatter containing the static text with single quotes around it, or [b] format the date-time alone and simply concatenate the static text.

I suggest instead you simple let Joda-Time choose a format localized to the user’s language and culture. See [`DateTimeFormat.forStyle`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html).